# Auto mount/umount USB and SD Card at runtime

Tags: linux, usb, mount, sd-card, udev

USB and SD Card is mounted at boot time. Below is my ***fstab*** :

```
/dev/sdg1    /mnt/usb1    auto    defaults,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0  0
/dev/sdh1    /mnt/usb2    auto    defaults,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0  0
/dev/mmcblk0p1    /mnt/sdcard     auto    defaults,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0  0
```

But after complete boot-up, when i disconnect and reconnect USB device again  then it is not auto-mounted again. I have added udev rules file ***/etc/udev/rules.d/99-auto-mount.rules*** for auto-mount as below

```
KERNEL=="sdg1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/sdg1"
KERNEL=="sdg1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/sdg1"
```

After that reload udev rules using below command:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

I properly umount device before disconnect USB. But it has no effect.

So i need help with some service or udev rules, through i can auto mount/umount device every time when i connect or disconnect device at runtime.